# MLE of $\beta$ (gamma distribution)

Tags: statistics, maximum-likelihood

> Consider a gamma distribution $\Gamma (\alpha,\beta)$ and $X = \{1.49,6.3,6.41,1.07,1.0,4.4,3.05,2.23,1.65,5.75\}$. Assume $\alpha = 3.5$, what's the MLE of $\beta$?

I started to calculate $$L(\beta | X)= \prod_{i=1}^{n}\frac{\beta^{\alpha}}{\Gamma(\alpha)}X_i^{\alpha-1}e^{-\beta X_i}$$

and by working with the logarithm I confirmed the maximum. $g_{\beta} = \log(L(\beta|X))$

\begin{align*}
&\frac{\partial g_{\beta}}{\partial \beta}=n\frac{\alpha}{\beta}-\sum_{i=1}^n X_i \Rightarrow \beta = \frac{\alpha}{\bar{X}}\\
&\frac{\partial^2 g_{\beta}}{\partial \beta^2} = -n\frac{\alpha}{\beta^2} <0
\end{align*}

So my solution is $\beta = \frac{35}{34.25}$ but the solution from the exercise is $\beta = \frac{34.25}{35}$. Did I forget something or is the example solution wrong?

Comment: Why $-\sum X_i$

Comment: @badinmaths Sorry, it's $e^{-\beta X_i}$

Comment: I think the question just uses a [different parametrisation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gamma_distribution) for the gamma distribution; their $\beta$ is your $\beta^{-1}$, which makes your answer correct.

Comment: @Adam aaah okay. Yes that makes sense.